# Going From State Verification to Behavioral Verification using MOQ

Tags: mocking, moq

I am trying to embrace TDD and started learning about mocking.  I need some advice on what i should test and how to make my classes more behavioral and not simple data containers (with a bunch of getters/setters).

Consider this class.

```
public class Post
{
   List<Comment> Comments {get; private set;}

   public void AddComment(string message)
   {
      Comment.Add(new Comment(message));
   } 
}
```

An example of a state verification test would be

```
[Test]
public void CanAddCommentToPost()
{
  Post p = new Post();
  p.AddComment("AAAAA");
  Assert.AreEqual(1,  Comments.Count);
}
```

I', not exactly sure what i should be doing for behavioural verification, can someone provide some samples using Moq?

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution to this question?  I'm pretty curious how this is going for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd have to redesign your Post class a bit, but no worries.

```
public class Post
{
     private IList<Comment> _comments;
     public Post(IList<Comment> commentContainer)
     {
          _comments = commentContainer;
     }

     public void AddComment(string message)
     {
          _comments.Add(new Comment(message));
     }
}
```

This slight redesign will give you the ability to use Moq to verify the behavior your are expecting.  I'll also show you a slightly better way to name your tests so that it's clear what they are trying to test.

```
[Test]
public void AddComment_NonNullMessage_IsAddedToCollection
{
     string message = "Test message";

     //Setup expectations
     Mock<IList<Comment>> commentsMock = new Mock<IList<Comment>>();
     commentsMock.Setup(list => list.Add(new Comment(message)));

     //Create target, passing in mock list
     Post target = new Post(commentsMock.Object);
     target.AddComment(message);

     //Verify our expectations are met
     commentsMock.VerifyAll();
}
```

And that is all.  The Mock will automatically throw an exception if all expectations are not met correctly.

Hope this helps.

-Anderson

Comment: +1. See also [moq Quickstart](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart) under Verification.

Comment: Your example doesn't work out of the box.  The setup fixture isnt matched as the comment passed in the setup is not equal to the comment newed up in the Post.AddComment method.  I changed the setup to list.Add(It.IsAny<Comment>()), my rationale being that I dont care about the message it contains but rather I am just verifying add is called.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot remember the moq syntax to hand but I see it like this.

Make Comments an a interface of IComments and assert that that Add is called on the interface.

Comment: This is pretty much the approach I took in my answer, but I went with a standard IList<Comment>, rather than a new interface IComments.